# ImportError: No module named scrapyproject.settings

Tags: python, scrapy

I have a scrapy project, the idea is to execute crawler and get the result back. I am using Flask as api end application and also using virtualenvironment.

```
from scrapy.spiderloader import SpiderLoader
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    settings = get_project_settings()
    loader = SpiderLoader(settings)
    spiders = loader.list()
    // validate spider
    cmd = "scrapy crawl test --nolog --output-format=json -o -"
    proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    output = proc.stdout.read()
    return Response(output, mimetype='application/json')
```

The problem is when the lines below are used inside executing the subprocess

```
settings = get_project_settings()
loader = SpiderLoader(settings)
spiders = loader.list()
```

the result is empty and it throws exceptions

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/www/projects/ENV/bin/scrapy", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(execute())
  File "/var/www/projects/ENV/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 108, in execute
    settings = get_project_settings()
  File "/var/www/projects/ENV/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/utils/project.py", line 60, in get_project_settings
    settings.setmodule(settings_module_path, priority='project')
  File "/var/www/projects/ENV/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/settings/__init__.py", line 282, in setmodule
    module = import_module(module)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named scrapyproject.settings
```

When the code to get the spiders list is commented it executes the test spider without any issues.

It is worth to note that the code to get all the spiders works fine.

```
@app.route("/spiders")
def spiders():
    settings = get_project_settings()
    loader = SpiderLoader(settings)
    jsonify(loader.list())
```

I have also looked into a few questions / answers mentioning it may be problem with virtualenvironment. But wondering why it only behaves when certain code is executed.

If you are wondering why I have not used / executed [scrapy via script](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html#run-scrapy-from-a-script) . What I need is to get the output without saving to any file system or db or anything via pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

[Christopher Davis](https://twitter.com/chrisguitarguy/status/775155136452624384) mentioned to pass the environment copy to subprocess.

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(..., env=os.environ.copy())
```

Which actually opened my eye to notice the introduction of `SCRAPY_SETTINGS_MODULE` once the `get_project_settings()` is called, which in turn when running the command to execute `scrapy` feels it is loaded. But not truly loaded.

So the solution is remove the environment variable as

```
del os.environ['SCRAPY_SETTINGS_MODULE']
```

before you call the subprocess.

Hope that will help someone and save their time.

Thank you